# how can i retrieve information from pubmed

Tags: r, pubmed

I have a set of pmid. I would like to know whether it is possible to get information like title, journal, issue, page number and abstract?

```
# Sample data
pmid<-c(8339401,8485120,8427851,3418853,3195585,2643302,7947591,8274474,8243847)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(RISmed)

e <- EUtilsGet(pmid)

ArticleTitle(e)
MedlineTA(e)
Volume(e)
Issue(e)
AbstractText(e)
MedlinePgn(e)
PMID(e) # same as pmid in question except character class

help(package = RISmed)
str(e)
```

Also google for: RISmed

For example:

```
> library(RISmed)
> e <- EUtilsGet(pmid)
> ArticleTitle(e)
[1] "LDL subclass phenotypes and the insulin resistance syndrome in women."                                                                 
[2] "Genetics of LDL subclass phenotypes in women twins. Concordance, heritability, and commingling analysis."                              
[3] "Effect of hepatic lipase on LDL in normal men and those with coronary artery disease."                                                 
[4] "Low-density lipoprotein subclass patterns and risk of myocardial infarction."                                                          
[5] "Inheritance of low-density lipoprotein subclass patterns: results of complex segregation analysis."                                    
[6] "Plasma triglyceride as a risk factor for coronary heart disease. The epidemiologic evidence and beyond."                               
[7] "Genetic predictors of FCHL in four large pedigrees. Influence of ApoB level major locus predicted genotype and LDL subclass phenotype."
[8] "Lack of association between sex hormones and Lp(a) concentrations in American and Finnish men."                                        
[9] "Is microalbuminuria part of the prediabetic state? The Mexico City Diabetes Study."
```

Comment: Did you install and load the package?  Is `pmid` identical to what you showed in the question?  It worked for me.

Comment: I found where the problem was. I had to reinstall the package because it was old or I dont know what. One question, would it be possible to add all those information in front of each title. for example, first paper, title, issue, volume, page and then abstract. Then below that , for the other etc?

Comment: `data.frame(title = ArticleTitle(e), ...etc..., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.